# PowerBI - Show lines on a map from one point to another

Tags: powerbi, polygon, arcgis, olap

We got several OLAP Cubes in PowerBI Datasets.

One of the cubes has a dimension "dim_location" which contains columns for latitude and longitude. But each dataset has 2 pairs of values, let's call them start_latitude, start_longitude and end_latitude, end_longitude.

I got a fact table connected to that dim_location and want to show some of the measures on a map.

It works perfectly fine with both the map visual and the ArcGIS visual, if I use either the end or the start coordinates. I can show the values as circles with changing size or changing color dependent on the value of a measure. So far so good.

But what I instead want to accomplish is to show a line on the map for each dataset. Each line shall go from start point to end point, color dependent on measure value.

Is there a way to offer the coordinates in the cube dimension in some string syntax that will create a shape, like a polygon with only 2 points, which would result in a line, which can then be shown on the map?

As stated before everything works fine on the map and the ArcGIS visual with one point (lat/lon) per dataset. Tried to find help online for some polygon syntax but came up empty.

Comment: You should look at https://www.icon-map.com/ for Power BI, it does lines, and may fit your use case